# Are the following 2 code snippets equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
};
```

code snippet 2:

```
var search = function(name){
    for(var prop in friends)
      {
         if(prop.firstName === name)
             {
                console.log(prop);
                return prop;
             }
      }
};
```

here friends is an object and firstName is one of the keys.

Comment: Just trying it out should show you the problem with the 2nd one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they'are not the same - for `friends` as an object in the second one `prop` is a property name and in first example iteration `friends[prop]` returns a values of the properties of the `friends` object.

With array it would be indexes - 0,1,2,3... for the second one and values for the first one.

Comment: thanks a lot, understood it finally..and @source.rar I asked the question so that I could understand what the problem was, not whether there was a problem,I didn't state that it was wrong to just make it more concise, anyways thanks for down voting my question,Cheers!